# Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm having a problem deploying my Blazor app to Azure Web App service trough the pipeline.
All steps are passing except the Azure web App service deploy.

[image]

It gives me the error:

```
**##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.**
```

This is the problematic YAML pipeline:

```
trigger:
 - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
   azureSubscription: 'Pay-As-You-Go (********-****-****-****-************)'
   appType: 'webApp'
   appName: 'Xenoprovider'
   package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
   deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help, I'm a one-man operation :)

Comment: Where the `zip` file created? in which location?

Comment: which file do you need to upload to the azure web app? zip file or razor file?

Comment: the thing is I'm not entirely sure. I guess I need  the zip file. My end goal is to publish the app as a production (make changes to repo then build and deploy). thing is I do this manually trough  Visual Studio -> Publish action. But now I would like to use Azure DevOps to automate that proces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missing here is actually publishing your project. So first please remove this:

```yaml
task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

you don't need to copy whole source code and then publish it as pipeline artifact.

Please make also sure you use correct version of dotnet core. You may check it in csproj `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` and then make sure with task below that correct version is installed:

```yaml
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.x'
```

Then please add step to publish your project similar to this one (before publishing pipeline/build artifact)

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(projectDirectory)\hadar.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true
```

and at the end please make sure you have correctly pass package in this step

```yaml
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: Azure Web App Deploy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appName: samplewebapp
    package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

Please notice that in that way you don't need to copy step because you publish to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and you look for package to publish in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and not in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Comment: Thank you. There is one problem with publish task: `Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1` followed by `[warning]Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x (3.1) SDK/Runtime along with 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions.` And finaly `[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\WEB\Xenoprovider\Xenoprovider.csproj
`

Comment: I believe I'm getting close to the solution here so I do thank you for the info.

Comment: What dotnet core version do you use? Please check this doc site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops You have there step to define dotnet core version.

Comment: Is there a way to check on Azre DevOps portal? But in my csproj it is defined as: `
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1"     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions"`

Comment: Please check `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` in your csproj.

Comment: Thank, I manage to get it published. If you can add the script for installing the SDK to your answer and it will be complete for all the noobs like me :)

Comment: Cool! I just did what you asked for.