# Can't find published DLL for deployment to Azure web service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm getting the following from my pipe.

> Script contents: dotnet publish
> ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
> /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/18bf48c0-d56c-4696-a002-26fa9f360fa5.sh
> MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET
> Determining projects to restore...
> Restored /home/vsts/work/1/s/Api/Api.csproj (in 3.05 sec).
> Api -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/Debug/net7.0/Api.dll
> Api -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/Debug/net7.0/publish/

I can clearly see that *Api.dll* has been created. However, in the next job, th eagent claims there's nothing matching the pattern.

> Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'app-temp'
> ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/*.dll
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

I even tried to set the path explicitly and can't see any difference between the announced placement of my DLL and the place the deployer looks at.

> Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'app-aux-identity-temp'
> ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/Debug/net7.0/Api.dll
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

What am I missing here?

I can only speculate that the file **must** be a ZIP but there's nothing I've found about such restriction in the docs. Also, in the wizard, it's even mentioned that the content may be ZIP, WAR or something that `dotnet build` has left. So is the case for me, as I run `dotnet build` prior to `dotnet publish`.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs if you have not specified proper path to your Build artifact. Reference [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569646/error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-1-s-zip) answer by Krzysztof Madej

***When I used the wrong path in package: of AzureWebApp@1 task even I received the same error code as yours***, Refer below:-

[image]

I used below YAML default pipeline to deploy my Asp .Net application to Azure Web app and it was successful, Refer below:-

I have referred [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive) and [MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the below YML pipeline and modified it.

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '6.x'

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 6.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)' # Update this to match your need


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'SID subscription(9)(0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'siliconwebapp32'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Updated answer:-***

Refer my [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440816/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-1-websitebr/76472534#76472534)

*According to my answer:-*

> **I have tried the deployment in 2 separate stages here. After
> downloading the Artifact from my build task to Deploy task I added `'$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'`  as my Artifact was downloaded in  `/home/vsts/work/1/publishedApp`  and the  [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for  `/home/vsts/work/1`  is  `Agent.BuildDirectory` Check the  predefined value for the path where your artifact is downloaded in Deploy stage.**

**My YAML script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'app-name'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two observations. First: I can't see a `download` step in your sample. That's where I got stuck. Second: I noticed that the publishing isn't required if the deployment is performed as a step within the same job/stage. However, if you wish to split those (publish and release) into separate jobs, then the results of the build/publish vanishes. Most people won't notice that because they use a single job for all the steps.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Refer my updated answer, I have tried to deploy web app with separate build and deploy stage, I also downloaded the artifact in deploy stage and it got downloaded to /home/vsts/work/1/publishedApp as predefined variables for  /home/vsts/work/1/ is Agent.BuildDirectory , Refer the predefined variables from here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml