# No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\website<br/>

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-web-app-service, devops, pipeline

I created a CI Pipeline in Azure DevOps with MsBuild to publish an artifact.
The build pipeline is working fine and publishes an artifact named 'website' (downloading the artifact as .zip)

```
variables:
# MsBuild@1 Variables
  buildSolution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}
  msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=true /p:WarningLevel=0 /p:publishUrl=$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\website /p:configuration=$(buildConfiguration)'
  buildArtifactName: website # PublishPipelineArtifactName

# Pipeline Start
stages:
- stage: BuildPublishArtifact
  jobs:
  - job:
    workspace:
      clean: ${{ variables.workspaceClean }}
    displayName: 'Build solution'

# Display Branch Name
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Display Branch, Commit and Build Configuration'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "Bulding Artifact named $(buildArtifactName) for Branch $(Build.SourceBranch) and Commit $(Build.SourceVersion) in Build Configuration $(buildConfiguration)"

# Restore NuGet packages
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: "Restore NuGet"
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(buildSolution)'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: '$(buildNuGet)'

# Build Artifact using MSBuild@1 task
    - task: MSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(buildSolution)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArguments: '$(msbuildArgs)'
        clean: true
        createLogFile: true
        logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'

# List Files
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Diagnostics - List Files'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: $(dir)

# List Files
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Diagnostics - List Build Artifact'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: $(dirArtifact)

#- stage: Run Tests
#  jobs: 
#  - job: RunAutomatedTests
#    displayName: 'Run Automated Tests'
#    steps:
#    - task: VSTest@2
#      displayName: 'Run automated tests'
#      inputs:
#        testAssemblyVer2: |
#          **\*test*.dll
#          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
#          !**\obj\**
#        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
#        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
#       configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

# Publish Pipeline Artifact
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/website'
        artifact: 'website'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Trying to deploy to Azure Web Apps through CD Pipeline, although I always end up with msg 'No package found with specfied pattern: D:\a\1\website
'
I don't get which directory I have to target in AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 to avoid this msg and get a successful deploy?

```
package: 'D:\a\1\website'
package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/website'
```

CD Pipeline
Can't tell if I actually need the "ExtractFiles@1"

```
stages:
  - stage: DownloadArtifactAndDeploy
    displayName: 'Deploy Artifact to Environments'
    jobs:
      - job: DownloadArtifact
        displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImage)
        steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'specific'
              project: '9035b146-1805-424b-913a-1e3ff3ec5b96'
              definition: '5593'
              buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
              targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

          - task: ExtractFiles@1
            inputs:
              archiveFilePatterns: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/*.zip'
              destinationFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/website'
              cleanDestinationFolder: true
              overwriteExistingFiles: false

      - ${{ if eq(parameters.deployToNonProd, true) }}:
        - job: DeployNonProd
          displayName: 'Deploy Artifact to NonProd'
          dependsOn: DownloadArtifact
          pool:
            vmImage: $(vmImage)
          steps:
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-NonProd'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'rg-haweb-cfs-dev-cms-single'
                package: 'D:\a\1\website'
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
                RuntimeStack: 'ASP.NET|4.7'
                TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
                ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: true
                RenameFilesFlag: true


      - ${{ if eq(parameters.deployToQA, true) }}:
        - job: DeployQA
          displayName: 'Deploy Artifact to QA'
          dependsOn: DownloadArtifact
          pool:
            vmImage: $(vmImage)
          steps:
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-QA'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'rg-haweb-cfs-qa-cms-single'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/website'
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
                RuntimeStack: 'ASP.NET|4.7'
                TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
                ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: true
                RenameFilesFlag: true

      - ${{ if eq(parameters.deployToProd, true) }}:
        - job: DeployProd
          displayName: 'Deploy Artifact to Prod'
          dependsOn: DownloadArtifact
          pool:
            vmImage: $(vmImage)
          steps:
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-Prod'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'rg-haweb-cfs-prod-cms-single'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/website'
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
                RuntimeStack: 'ASP.NET|4.7'
                TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
                ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: true
                RenameFilesFlag: true
```

Log message from AzureRmWebAppDeployment

```
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_ac049b99-4397-487c-ba76-490f2fff88ae
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_ADDITIONALARGUMENTS
##[debug]loading INPUT_CONNECTEDSERVICENAME
##[debug]loading INPUT_CONNECTIONTYPE
##[debug]loading INPUT_DEPLOYMENTTYPE
##[debug]loading INPUT_DEPLOYTOSLOTORASEFLAG
##[debug]loading INPUT_EXCLUDEFILESFROMAPPDATAFLAG
##[debug]loading INPUT_INLINESCRIPT
##[debug]loading INPUT_PACKAGE
##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILEPATH
##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEADDITIONALFILESFLAG
##[debug]loading INPUT_RENAMEFILESFLAG
##[debug]loading INPUT_RUNTIMESTACK
##[debug]loading INPUT_SCRIPTPATH
##[debug]loading INPUT_SETPARAMETERSFILE
##[debug]loading INPUT_SLOTNAME
##[debug]loading INPUT_TAKEAPPOFFLINEFLAG
##[debug]loading INPUT_USEWEBDEPLOY
##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBAPPKIND
##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBAPPNAME
##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLTRANSFORMATION
##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLVARIABLESUBSTITUTION
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 31
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]agent.proxyurl=undefined
##[debug]VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS=undefined
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_ccbf3a83-7845-4e2d-9520-e48169652e72_build_5910_0
##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=D:\a\_temp
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json
##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\task.json
##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-webdeployment-common\module.json
##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.223.2\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-webdeployment-common\module.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]ConnectionType=AzureRM
##[debug]WebAppKind=webApp
##[debug]DeployToSlotOrASEFlag=false
##[debug]GenerateWebConfig=undefined
##[debug]WebConfigParameters=undefined
##[debug]XmlTransformation=false
##[debug]JSONFiles=undefined
##[debug]XmlVariableSubstitution=false
##[debug]TakeAppOfflineFlag=true
##[debug]RenameFilesFlag=true
##[debug]AdditionalArguments=-retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000
##[debug]ScriptType=undefined
##[debug]InlineScript=:: You can provide your deployment commands here. One command per line.
##[debug]ScriptPath=D:\a\1\s
##[debug]DockerNamespace=undefined
##[debug]AppSettings=undefined
##[debug]StartupCommand=undefined
##[debug]ConfigurationSettings=undefined
##[debug]ConnectedServiceName=ac049b99-4397-487c-ba76-490f2fff88ae
##[debug]WebAppName=rg-haweb-cfs-qa-cms-single
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskEndpointId;feature=AzureRmWebAppDeployment]{"endpointId":"ac049b99-4397-487c-ba76-490f2fff88ae"}
##[debug]Package=D:\a\1\website
##[debug]Finding files matching input: D:\a\1\website
##[debug]No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\website
##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\website<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\website<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\website<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\website<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
##[debug]Deployment failed
Finishing: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
```

How can I copy all those files from the build folder to Azure Web Apps?

Tried changing the package value in the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 to various values... I'm out of options...

Comment: why are you doing it through the  build pipeline and not creating a release pipeline? If you're looking for the artifact directory it goes in a zip file. `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Good question tbh. I'm quite new in my position, so still trying to figure out what's the best/most correct approach.

Comment: In devops you should create a release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

When I added  `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'` and `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'` in package while deploying web app I received the same error code as yours.

**Error:-**

[image]

I downloaded the Artifact from my build task to Deploy task and added  `'$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'` as my artifact was downloaded in `/home/vsts/work/1/publishedApp` and the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for `/home/vsts/work/1` is `Agent.BuildDirectory`-

**My YAML pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valleyweb-app'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]